# How to interpret the ks_2samp with alternative ='less' or alternative ='greater'

Tags: python, scipy

I have two sets of data:

```
A = df['Users_A'].values
B = df['Users_B'].values
```

I am using this scipy function:

```
pval_less = stats.mstats.ks_2samp(A,B, alternative='less')[1]
p_val_greater = stats.mstats.ks_2samp(A,B, alternative='greater')[1]
```

For these two I have these results:

```
pval_less = 1.05465e-51 
p_val_greater = 1.97441e-220
```

How should I interpret these results?

Ususally `p_val_greater = 1 - p_val_less` and the opposite. Then I know if set A has 'greater/less' values than set B with the specified probability.

Here, I am not sure how to do it. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

The Notes section of the [`ks_2samp` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html) in recent releases of SciPy give interpretations of the different null and alternative hypotheses.

> This test compares the underlying continuous distributions F(x) and G(x) of two independent samples.
>
> - less: The null hypothesis is that F(x) >= G(x) for all x; the alternative is that F(x) < G(x) for at least one x. The statistic is the magnitude of the minimum (most negative) difference between the empirical distribution functions of the samples.
> - greater: The null hypothesis is that F(x) <= G(x) for all x; the alternative is that F(x) > G(x) for at least one x. The statistic is the maximum (most positive) difference between the empirical distribution functions of the samples.

Since both p-values are small, you have evidence against the null hypothesis in favor of two alternative hypotheses, which are *not* mutually exclusive: F(x) < G(x) for at least one x *and* F(x) > G(x) for at least one x.

As an example:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dist1 = stats.norm()
dist2 = stats.uniform(loc=-5, scale=10)
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 300)

plt.plot(x, dist1.cdf(x), label='normal')
plt.plot(x, dist2.cdf(x), label='uniform')
plt.legend()

x1 = dist1.rvs(1000)
x2 = dist2.rvs(1000)

resL = stats.ks_2samp(x1, x2, alternative='less')
resG = stats.ks_2samp(x1, x2, alternative='greater')
print(resL.pvalue, resG.pvalue)
# 1.0166514431699959e-34 5.072797825961067e-38
```

[image]

The CDF of the distribution underlying `x1` (normal) is less than the CDF of the distribution underlying `x2` (uniform) at some points, and it is greater at others, so the test reports small p-values for both alternatives.